# INNER JOIN Alias sintax

Tags: inner-join

I have this

SELECT
              p.id,
              p.name,
              p.code,
              clA.code as claCode,
              sclA.code as sclaCode,
              clB.code as clbCode,
              sclB.code as sclbCode,
              clC.code as clcCode,
              sclC.code as sclcCode

```
FROM 
             products p
                 INNER JOIN catleathers clA
                    ON p.catleather_id_a = clA.id
                 INNER JOIN subcatleathers sclA
                    ON p.subcatleather_id_a = sclA.id
                 INNER JOIN catleathers clB
                    ON p.catleather_id_b = clB.id
                 INNER JOIN subcatleathers sclB
                    ON p.subcatleather_id_b = sclB.id
                 INNER JOIN catleathers clC
                    ON p.catleather_id_c = clC.id
                 INNER JOIN subcatleathers sclC
                   ON p.subcatleather_id_c = sclC.id
```

But I need something like this

```
function getdatatableajaxcost()
   {

   $this->load->library('datatables');
   $this->datatables

    ->select("



            products.id as productid, 
            products.code as code, 
            products.name as name, 

            clA.code as claCode,
            sclA.code as sclaCode,
            clB.code as clbCode,
            sclB.code as sclbCode,
            clC.code as clcCode,
            sclC.code as sclcCode,

            products.details", FALSE)

            ->from('products')
            ->join('catleathers clA', 'products.catleather_id_a = clA.id', 'INNER')
            ->join('subcatleathers sclA', 'products.subcatleather_id_a = sclA.id', 'INNER')
             ->join('catleathers clB', 'products.catleather_id_a = clB.id', 'INNER')
            ->join('subcatleathers sclB', 'products.subcatleather_id_a = sclB.id', 'INNER')
            ->join('catleathers clC', 'products.catleather_id_a = clC.id', 'INNER')
            ->join('subcatleathers sclC', 'products.subcatleather_id_a = sclC.id', 'INNER')
            ->group_by("products.id");

          $this->datatables->unset_column('productid');
          $this->datatables->unset_column('image');

           echo $this->datatables->generate();
```

Some help please!

Comment: Hard to understand what you are asking.

Comment: Are you trying to port your query to a different language?

Comment: Not really..
I have a datatable function and I need to add more collumns inside. Please take a look on edited above. This is made in codeigniter

Comment: The original code is something like this ->from('products')
   ->join('categories', 'products.category_id=categories.id', 'left')
   ->join('subcategories', 'products.subcategory_id=subcategories.id', 'left')

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
Thanks all!

```
 ->select("

            products.id as productid, 
            products.image as image, 
            products.code as code, 
            products.name as name, 
            categories.name as cname, 
            subcategories.name as subcategory, 
            products.cost, 
            products.price,  

            clA.code as claCode,
            sclA.code as sclaCode,
            clB.code as clbCode,
            sclB.code as sclbCode,
            clC.code as clcCode,
            sclC.code as sclcCode,

            catSoleA.code as catSoleACode,
            subcatSoleA.code as subcatSoleACode,

            catSoleB.code as catSoleBCode,
            subcatSoleB.code as subcatSoleBCode,

            catSoleC.code as catSoleCCode,
            subcatSoleC.code as subcatSoleCCode,

            products.details", FALSE)

            ->from('products')
            ->join('categories', 'products.category_id=categories.id', 'left')
            ->join('subcategories', 'products.subcategory_id=subcategories.id', 'left')

            ->join('catleathers clA', 'products.catleather_id_a = clA.id', 'INNER')
            ->join('subcatleathers sclA', 'products.subcatleather_id_a = sclA.id', 'INNER')

            ->join('catleathers clB', 'products.catleather_id_b = clB.id', 'INNER')
            ->join('subcatleathers sclB', 'products.subcatleather_id_b = sclB.id', 'INNER')

            ->join('catleathers clC', 'products.catleather_id_c = clC.id', 'INNER')
            ->join('subcatleathers sclC', 'products.subcatleather_id_c = sclC.id', 'INNER')

            ->join('catsoles catSoleA', 'products.catsole_id_a = catSoleA.id', 'INNER')
            ->join('subcatsoles subcatSoleA', 'products.subcatsole_id_a = subcatSoleA.id', 'INNER')

            ->join('catsoles catSoleB', 'products.catsole_id_b = catSoleB.id', 'INNER')
            ->join('subcatsoles subcatSoleB', 'products.subcatsole_id_b = subcatSoleB.id', 'INNER')

            ->join('catsoles catSoleC', 'products.catsole_id_c = catSoleC.id', 'INNER')
            ->join('subcatsoles subcatSoleC', 'products.subcatsole_id_c = subcatSoleC.id', 'INNER')


            ->group_by("products.id");
```